# Optocoupler (Analog or Digital)

Tags: opto-isolator

I have got few analog and digital signal that needs to be galvanically isolated. I am thinking to use [H11F1M](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/H1/H11F3M.pdf) for analog signals. I am not sure how to rig-up the circuit using this device. Specifically bias resistors to be connected on LED and FET side.

And can the same device be used for digital signals also. And what precautions shall I take while using it for analog signals or digital signal.

EDIT1:
I want to isolate RSSI generated from [AD8367](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD8367.pdf). RSSI vs Voltage graph on Page 10.

Apart from [HCNR200](http://www.avagotech.com/docs/AV02-0886EN) from Avago as a solution.

I got a [application note](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/AN559.pdf) from Silabs which claims to use [Si8660](https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/Si866x.pdf) for isolation of analog signal as it has internal RF Modulator and Demodulator based on [OOK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-off_keying). But I am not sure whether analog signal can directly be fed to this chip of I need to use some extrnal opamps as shown in the [Evaluation Board](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/Si86xx-IsoLin.pdf) of Si866x.

Comment: Is this a one-off or for production (i.e., are you interested in price differences of a few dollars)?  Also, what is the voltage range of the analog signal?

Comment: What is the bandwidth of the analog signal, and with what accuracy do you need to get it accross the isolation barrier?  Converting to digital then sending that accross isolation has many advantages.  Why can't you do that?

Comment: @ScottSeidman: It is for the production only.

Comment: @OlinLathrop:Analog signals are RSSI of some RF signal.

Comment: Do the analog/digital signals have to be galvanically isolated _only from the control signal_ or also from _each other_? If the first situation is the case it is enough to use standard anlalog switch/MUX (4015, 4051, 4067 or similar) and only isolate the (digital) control signal(-s).

Comment: @Curd:But switch will not provide galvanic isolation right?

Comment: To get galvanic isolation on analog signals you need an linear optocouplers. See related question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18039/galvanic-separation-between-a-microcontroller-and-a-motor-driver

Comment: @AKR: it will provide galvanic isolation between signals and control, not between signals, but the same is the case with the Opto-FET device if used as switch: it also will NOT provide galvanic isolation between signals, only between signal and control.

Comment: @m.Alin -- I think he might be able to use his analog signal as a variable gain for a constant voltage source, as shown in the datasheet.  I'm not real familiar w/ his IC choice, but it looks doable with the choice of IC (I just don't know how well!).  If money were no object, I would have suggested something like an HCNR200 (at least for non-neg signals), but its for production.

Comment: Telling us the signals are RSSI is of some interest, but that doesn't answer the questions I actually asked.  Since you refuse to cooperate, the only thing left to do is to close the question.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Give me some time Sir, I need to check other details.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Updated the question Sir.

Comment: What will you use that RSSI signal for? Is there any reason not to digitize the signal there as Olin proposed?

Comment: The analog thing in that app-note (As an aside: Holy shit horrible schematics!) is using a external circuit to convert the input voltage into a PWM signal, isolating that, and then reconstituting the PWM into a analog signal on the other side of the isolation barrier. The actual SI parts are digital only.

Comment: I have used the SIlabs isolators before. They're quite nice, and use much less power then similarly specified Analog Devices ADuM isolators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the analog part might be achievable by using your analog signal as a variable gain amp that has a a constant voltage source as an input, as suggested in the datasheet.  I'm not real familiar w/ this IC choice, but it looks doable with the choice of IC (I just don't know how well!).  If money were no object, I would have suggested something like an HCNR200 (at least for non-neg signals), but its for production.

Comment: Any views on Si8660

Comment: I avoid silabs products because I didn't feel they were responsive to my needs during my only interaction with them.  They refused to sample me because I'm at a university, and they wouldn't tell me about life cycle of a product I was interested in.  Not that I hold a grudge!

Comment: @ScottSeidman I share your view on SiLabs: Manufacturers who are shy about sampling are not keen on my business, or that of my clients. So I make sure they don't get any of the business. A generous sampling policy such as TI's leads to a natural increase in incorporation of that manufacturer's parts into every design. It's business sense, not a grudge.